# System.InvalidOperationException: "ExecuteNonQuery: Свойство Connection не инициализировано."

Tags: c#, winforms, access

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string query = "INSERT INTO Данные (Имя, Оценки) VALUES (@imya,@ochenki)";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, MyConnection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imya", textBox4.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ochenki", label10.Text); // Поле "Оценки" в таблице типа символьное, иначе требуется преобразование типа
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\HOME\\Desktop\\Новая папка (3)\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\Анкета.accdb");
            Application.Exit();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы проверяли, что `MyConnection` не `null`?

Comment: @VladD Да. Помогите решить

Comment: Проверяли, и там не-null?

Comment: не вижу, где у вас `MyConnection.Open()`?

Comment: @aepot                                                                                                                                           public partial class Form36 : Form
    {                                                                                                                                                   
       string ConnectionString= @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Анкета.accdb";
        private OleDbConnection MyConnection;

Comment: Чтобы соединение проинициализировать, надо его сначала создать `MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)`, а потом открыть `MyConnection.Open()`

Comment: @aepot куда вставить код?

Comment: Например в обработчик события `Form_Load`. Или просто в обработчик кнопки. Только после того как закончите работать с базой, не забудьте закрыть соединение `MyConnection.Close()`.

Comment: @aepot Не получилось. Красным показывает

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @aepot Вы знаете, как сделать чтобы оценка и имя были на одной строчке, то есть 2 формы ?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, задайте его отдельно со всеми деталями

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое за помощь. Получилось